# Background color in rotated text cell not correct size

Tags: html, css, rotation, html-table

I have rotated text in a table cell but the background color is not filling the cell.  I have search StackOverflow and tried pretty much every answers I 
could find to no avail.  Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eoar08fx/

HTML:

```
<td rowspan='4'>
     <div class='vertical-text'>Activities</div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical-text {
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #2E9AFE;

-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* accepts left, right, top, bottom */
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;

/* do not set in IE9+? */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation = 3);
}
```

Thanks for any tips or points.

Comment: `<td rowspan='4' style="background-color: #2E9AFE;">`

Comment: you could also look at writing-mode https://jsfiddle.net/eoar08fx/3/ & https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode or control width and rotate and translate https://jsfiddle.net/eoar08fx/2/ _for a single cell.you may use a child with a negative margin to reduce virually width and a pseudo to increase height with vertical % padding http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/EvCHi ._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've set the background on the `div` inside the cell, not to the cell, you need to apply the background color to the `td` and rotate the text inside the `div`

```
<td rowspan='4' class='vertical-text'>
     <div >Activities</div>
</td>
```

and

```
.vertical-text  {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   background-color: #2E9AFE;
   }
.vertical-text div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   transform: rotate(-90deg);

   /* accepts left, right, top, bottom */
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;

   /* do not set in IE9+? */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation = 3);
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/grassog/51mhy9qe/1/

Comment: Gah!  How could I have missed that?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the `cell-blue` CSS class property you created to your `td` conatining the `div` which contains the text itself.

It should fill the `td` instead of only filling the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is indeed to set background to the cell via the class you use else where.

---

For the width , 2 options below

---

You can also use the writing-mode propertie for this (longtime ago it use to be an IE 5 feature). It might avoid to deal with the width of that cell.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms531187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```css
.vertical-text {
  margin:0 0 0 1em;
  line-height:0.5em;
  max-height:4em;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-writing-mode:vertical-lr;/* old windows safari */
  writing-mode:vertical-lr;
  writing-mode:tb-lr;
  direction:ltr;
  transform:scale(-1,-1);/* orientation can be reversed */

}
.cell-blue {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #2E9AFE;
}

.cell-grey {
  color: #DEF0F6;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
}

td.wide-cell {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 45px;
  width: 300px;
}

td.short-cell {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 45px;
  width: 70px;
}

.centered-cell {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:30px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="wide-cell cell-blue">
         DATE
      </td>
      <td class="short-cell cell-blue">
         YTD
      </td>
      <td class="short-cell cell-blue">
         Q1
      </td>
      <td class="short-cell cell-blue">
         Q2
      </td>
      <td class="short-cell cell-blue">
         Q3
      </td>
      <td class="short-cell cell-blue">
         Q4
      </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td rowspan='4' class='cell-blue'><!-- it deserves the cell-blue class doesn't it ? */
         <div class='vertical-text'>Activities</div>
      </td>
      <td class='left-cell cell-blue'>
         Setup Y/N
      </td>
      <td class='centered-cell cell-grey'>
         <div id='setupYTD'></div>
      </td>
      <td class='centered-cell cell-grey'>
         <div id='setupQ1'></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id='setupQ2'></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id='setupQ3'></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id='setupQ4'></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="left-cell cell-blue">
         Objectives
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="objYTD"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="objQ1"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="objQ2"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="objQ3"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="objQ4"></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="left-cell cell-blue">
         Project
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="assessmentYTD"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="assessmentQ1"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="assessmentQ2"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="assessmentQ3"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="assessmentQ4"></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="left-cell cell-blue">
         Outcome
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="outcomeYTD"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="outcomeQ1"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="outcomeQ2"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="outcomeQ3"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="outcomeQ4"></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EKQKBe)**

---

Or use negative margin and pseudo to make sure it does the required height:

```css
[rowspan] {/*whatever selector you want to use ,  vertical-text class could be set onto the cell to make things easier :) */
  min-width:1em;
  vertical-align:bottom;/* decide to start from bottom or top to not mind text length */
  
}
.vertical-text {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height:1.5em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float:left;
  margin-right:-999px;/* reduce width virtually to very little */
  transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%,0);/* rotate and replace */
  transform-origin:top left;
}
.vertical-text:before{/* here we go look for the height the text is suppose to use */
  content:'';
  float:left;
  padding-top:100%;/* might be increased a little */
}

/* regular stuff */
.cell-blue {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #2E9AFE;
}

.cell-grey {
  color: #DEF0F6;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
}

td.wide-cell {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 45px;
  width: 300px;
}

td.short-cell {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 45px;
  width: 70px;
}

.centered-cell {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:30px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="wide-cell cell-blue">
         DATE
      </td>
      <td class="short-cell cell-blue">
         YTD
      </td>
      <td class="short-cell cell-blue">
         Q1
      </td>
      <td class="short-cell cell-blue">
         Q2
      </td>
      <td class="short-cell cell-blue">
         Q3
      </td>
      <td class="short-cell cell-blue">
         Q4
      </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td rowspan='4' class='cell-blue'>
         <div class='vertical-text'>Activities</div>
      </td>
      <td class='left-cell cell-blue'>
         Setup Y/N
      </td>
      <td class='centered-cell cell-grey'>
         <div id='setupYTD'></div>
      </td>
      <td class='centered-cell cell-grey'>
         <div id='setupQ1'></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id='setupQ2'></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id='setupQ3'></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id='setupQ4'></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="left-cell cell-blue">
         Objectives
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="objYTD"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="objQ1"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="objQ2"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="objQ3"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="objQ4"></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="left-cell cell-blue">
         Project
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="assessmentYTD"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="assessmentQ1"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="assessmentQ2"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="assessmentQ3"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="assessmentQ4"></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="left-cell cell-blue">
         Outcome
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="outcomeYTD"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="outcomeQ1"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="outcomeQ2"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="outcomeQ3"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="centered-cell cell-grey">
         <div id="outcomeQ4"></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MyQeYV)**